# How to partially update the instance using `ModelForms`

Tags: python, django, django-forms

I have a `Model` with 5 fields. I create a `ModelForm` on top of that model, now I intialize the form with request data containing 4 fields.

The reason of 4 fields in request data is the checkbox on frontend that isn't passed using jquery `FormData` when unchecked.

Now the problem is, I want to set a default value of the 5th field at the time of form initialization if checkbox is not passed in request data.

What would be the best thing to do, set default value in `ModelForm` or `Form` or use default value from `Model` or I can set the value of a specific field.

Sugesstions are welcome. TIA.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can mess around with `request.POST` before binding it to the form. If you are using CBV `FormView` you can subclass `get_form_kwargs`. Something like

```
# UNTESTED CODE

def get_form_kwargs(self):
    kwargs = super().get_form_kwargs()
    if self.request.method in ('POST', 'PUT'):
        if 'foo' not in kwargs['data']:
            #this starts as request.POST which is an immutable QueryDict
            data = kwargs['data'].copy() # mutable copy
            data['foo'] = 'whatever' #supply the missing default value
            kwargs['data'] = data
    return kwargs
```

Consult the Django documentation w.r.t. `QueryDict`. They are tricky beasts that are directory-like but the differences can be enough to catch you out. It's easy to create one at the shell prompt and play with it to make sure you get this right.

Comment: I am not using CBV FormView but CBV Views only. I appreciate your input but I am looking for something to that would pick default value given in model. 

Or there is some way we could exclude one field from is_valid() on form ?

Comment: You can do the same modification of request.POST in a function-based view if that's what you are using. Take a copy and insert the default before binding the form to `request.POST`.  I don't offhand know how to extract the default from a model "efficiently", but you could instantiate one and use the value of the field: `default = Foo().foo`